# Setting Value on PHP Zend Form

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, default-value

I currently have a form that will let you create a family.

**FamilyForm.php**

```
$description = new Textarea(self::KEY_FAMILY_DESCRIPTION);
$description->setAttribute("id", self::KEY_FAMILY_DESCRIPTION);
$description->setLabel("Description");
$this->add($description);    

$status = new Hidden(self::KEY_FAMILY_STATUS);
$status->setAttribute("id", self::KEY_FAMILY_STATUS); 
$this->add($status); 

$save = new Button(self::KEY_SAVE_BTN);
$save->setAttributes(array("id", self::KEY_SAVE_BTN));
$save->setLabel("Save");
$save->setValue("Save");
$this->add($save);
```

**Create.phtml**

```
<?php echo ctrlGroup($this, ProjectFamilyForm::KEY_FAMILY_DESCRIPTION, !($this->admin)); ?>
<?php echo ctrlGroup($this, ProjectFamilyForm::KEY_FAMILY_STATUS, !($this->admin)); ?>
<div class="form-actions">
      <?php $save = $this->form->get(ProjectFamilyForm::KEY_SAVE_BTN); ?>
      <?php $save->setAttribute("class", "btn btn-primary"); ?>
      <?php echo $this->formSubmit($save); ?>

      <a class="btn" href="<?php echo $this->url('home'); ?>">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

This works and allows me to input the description and the status of the family upon creation.  However, everytime a family is created the `status` should be `"active"`.  However, the `setValue()` method seems to not be working.

Comment: *"but I get an error"* - Being what *exactly?*

Comment: @A-2-A yeah, missed it on my copy and paste -_-

Comment: @Fred-ii- `Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object `

Comment: @A-2-A but is there any way I can do it from the form?

Comment: *Hm....* not sure but you have `setAttributes` in plural from and `setAttribute` in singular form. *Relevant?*. Or, are they 2 seperate methods?

Comment: @Fred-ii- they are two separate methods

Comment: You could try and use ternary operator. I for one am out of ideas at this point, sorry. and I don't know Zend.

Comment: @A-2-A That's what I'm looking into now. I've hidden the form, but using `setValue()` doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not expert of `ZEND` but to do this some ways are there:-

1. most preferable way:- Make you db table field `set` type and set the default value to `active`.
2. Create a hidden field with predefined `active` value.

Please check this link for help:- http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?t=2079

Comment: I ended up using the hidden field and got it working. Thanks!